# exporting SQL from a Viso diagram

Tags: sql, visio

Is there a method to export SQL statements from a Viso 2003 entity-relationship diagram?

Comment: Check these add-ins for Visio forward engineering http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/visio-forward-engineer http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visio 2010 and have a 64-bit OS, this add-in may help:
http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a very useful tool, the current version also adds validates the design if you have missing info in the diagram or duplicates and other useful validations.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which edition of Visio you have.

There's an Enterprise edition pr Professional edition which has a `database` menu item that will export (and import) database schema from Visio.

If you have some lower edition, you may not have any database engineering or reverse engineering features.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think it's possible with Visio, the best you can do is go to the SQL Server Diagram window (Database Diagram) and right click on the empty white space on the Diagram-- there's an option "Copy Diagram to Clipboard", you can paste in MSPaint or Photoshop.