# Exporting Entity-Relationship-Diagram from SQL with Visio 2010 (Professional Plus)

Tags: sql, export, entity-relationship, diagram, visio

I'm searching the opposite solution to the question [exporting SQL from a Viso diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506012/exporting-sql-from-a-viso-diagram). I have the SQL statement for the creation of multiple tables of a MySQL database. Is there a way to use the Reverse-Engineering feature of Visio 2010 to create a diagram thereof?

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a Access database from the SQL statement (MySQL) where Visio could connect ... Alternative I'll try to use another MySQL database, create the tables there, and try to connect with Visio to this database. Any instructions how to do this? Other ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Import SQL into Access and use Visio :

Access is incompatible with MySQL statements. You would have to translate all the statements and only one statement is allowed at the time. Not very convenient. More info at: http://help.lockergnome.com/office2/sql-text-file-import-Access--ftopict720045.html

If you have finished use these instructions:
http://blog.pearltechnology.com/creating-entity-relationship-diagram-in-visio/

2) Create tables again in new MySQL environment and use Visio:

Follow the instructions listed here http://sajjadhossain.com/2009/02/12/reverse-engineering-mysql-database-with-microsoft-visio/comment-page-1/

Problems I had:

- Got the error "Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". Use phpmyadmin and go to rights, where you change the host of your user (e.g. to %)
- In the instructions above I used in step 12 the "ODBC Generic driver" ( http://maniish.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/reverse-engineer-mysql-in-visio-2007/)

3) Use MySQL Workbench:

Click on Database -> Reverse Engineer

Most convenient but can't decide between option 2 and 3, because of graphical representation and level of detail.

4) Use other software:

http://forums.devshed.com/database-management-46/tool-to-generate-er-diagram-from-sql-code-59569.html